# White Screen after boot to 6.2.0-33 generic kernel

Tags: boot, nvidia, upgrade, kernel, graphics

After updating to 6.2.0-33 kernel from 5.19, my computer boots to a login screen, but when I login the screen is completely white. The cursor is still visible. I have nvidia-driver-470 installed but I've tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it. I've also tried including "nomodeset" in DEFAULT_GRUB, which worked when I didn't have nvidia drivers installed, but for some reason didn't find my other monitor? I'm very new to Ubuntu and trying to learn the basics.

I have an AMD Ryzen 9 7950X and a Nvidia 3070ti. It seems like it could be a graphics issue from what I've read, but looking for any guidance for an approach I haven't tried.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 reached EOL back in late July (5.19 being the HWE kernel from 22.10) thus the kernel upgraded to 6.2 from 23.04 some time ago and not what I consider recently (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-meta-hwe-6.2/linux-meta-hwe-6.2_6.2.0.33.33~22.04.10/changelog). Ubuntu LTS releases have  kernel stack options (GA or the initial LTS stack the system releases with; ie. 5.15, or HWE which changes using stacks from later releases; third options of OEM I'm ignoring). Using GA maybe an option - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack